# Get value from array

Tags: php, html

I've following php code which store value to an Array called ch[].

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='ch[$roll]['$sname']['$class']' value='1' />&nbsp;";
echo "<input type='radio' name='ch[$roll]['$sname']['$class']' value='0' />";
```

Now I can get only **$roll** and **value** wtih following code

```
foreach($_POST['ch'] as $id=>$value)
{
echo "id = $id ";
echo "VAlue = $value; <br/>";                       
}
```

but I want to get the value of **$sname, $class** variable. Is there anyway to get these value. Can you guys give me a idea or solutions ?
Thank You.

**Updated:**

```
foreach ($_POST['ch'] as $roll => $arr1)
                {
                echo $roll;
                   foreach ($arr1 as $name => $arr2)
                   {
                    echo $name;
                       foreach ($arr2 as $class => $value)
                       {
                           echo $class;
                           echo $value;

  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_attendence VALUES('', '$sname', '$roll', '$class', 
'$value', '$current_date')");
                       }
                   }
                }
```

Comment: do you actually get the value from `$value`, aren't you getting "Array"?

Comment: @koala_dev I want to get the value from all variable which is $roll, $sname, $class and Value='1' or '0'

Comment: @Alex I get that, but you're saying you CAN get the value with your code, but I don't think that's the case

Comment: @koala_dev I want get all the variable and value='1' or '0' so that I can insert it to the db in the same time.

Comment: use $name instead of $sname

Comment: @koala_dev now problem is about the class. It's insert same class.

Comment: Then the problem is in how you build your radio buttons

Comment: @koala_dev can i upload my more code of the table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try

```
foreach ($_POST['ch'] as $roll => $arr1)
{
   echo $roll;
   foreach ($arr1 as $name => $arr2)
   {
       echo $name;
       foreach ($arr2 as $class => $value)
       {
           echo $class;
           echo $value;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: @koala_dev I updated my questions please check it. Now it's can get all the value but sql query can't insert accurate value to the db.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same code as written bellow :

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='ch[$roll]['$sname']['$class']' value='1' />&nbsp;";
echo "<input type='radio' name='ch[$roll]['$sname']['$class']' value='0' />";
```

Then please remove `'` from `ch[$roll]['$sname']['$class']` because if you can inspect the html you will find that the radio buttons are not created properly and never use inverted commas in html input array.

After fixing this please try

```
echo (int)$_REQUEST['ch'][$roll][$sname][$class];
```

May this helps you.